# UITableViewCell didn't register

Tags: swift, uitableview

I got problem and information in debug area.

> unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

But in inspector all right! 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should set cell identifier in `Attributes inspector`.

[image: cell identifier in Attributes inspector]